# How do you register a new user (with attributes) in Hyperledger Fabric Client (HFC)?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am reviewing the sample code for the HFC SDK and saw ways to manage users.

To enroll an existing user the following function is used:

```
chain.enroll
```

To register and enroll a new user the following function is used:

```
chain.registerAndEnroll
```

However, the sample code did not provide an example for a register only function:

```
chain.register
```

If I understand it correctly both the chain.enroll and chain.registerAndEnroll will both save the user key/certificate in the machine where the functions are called.

If I want an admin to create a new user (e.g., userA), I cannot use the chain.registerAndEnroll function since the key/certificate will be saved in the admin's machine instead of userA's machine since the function performs not only a register but also an enroll.  Hence, my need for a register only function.

In addition, how do I add attributes to users using HFC similar to the attributes that can be defined in membersrvc.yaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I was unable to find an online link to the hfc API doc (although you can build the doc locally if needed).

That being said, there is a `chain.register` function which takes a `RegistrationRequest` object and then returns the enroll secret/password you would later use to enroll the new user:

```
//create some attributes
var attributes = [{name:'foo',value:'bar'}];
var registrationRequest = {
     roles: [ role ],
     enrollmentID: name,
     affiliation: "bank_a",
     attributes: attributes,
     registrar: registrar
};

chain.register(registrationRequest, function(err, enrollmentPassword) { 
    //your code here
```

}

Comment: Thanks @Gari.  This is very helpful.  I'll try this.  I'd like to confirm if I understand correctly how to typically use the chain.register function:  This function is used by the admin (and not by a regular user).  The enrollmentID and enrollmentPassword will be sent by the admin through e-mail (or other means) to the user.  The user will use the chain.enroll function to get his/her private key/certificate files.  In this approach, a malicious admin may attempt to enroll in behalf of the user but this will be detected by the user since chain.enroll can be called only once.  Is this correct?